# Can not switch to waylan in 22.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, wayland

Just updated to  22.04 and read that it now supports wayland for nvidia card with nvidia 510 driver. I've got nvidia 2080 super and I can not see the cog in the right bottom corner on the login screen. Changing WaylandEnabled to true in config file doesn't work as well.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you remove the # (comment indicator) on the  config line and reboot as well?

Comment: In login screen, tried clicking on the user icon first(so it asks for the password), Then on the right bottom seeing the cog wheel ?

Comment: For now, no Wayland with Nvidia. The Nvidia drivers are not up to the task yet.

Comment: Also nvidia users should be put on Wayland, but it depends perhaps on the type of card. The site is currently flooded with nvidia users having graphical issues. I recommend staying on Xorg for the time being.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the tip. I thought it's solved in nvidia 510.

Comment: Seems its a [bug already reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1968929)

Answer (score 3):

sudo open /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules

```sh
LABEL="gdm_prefer_xorg"
#RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm-runtime-config set daemon PreferredDisplayServer xorg"
GOTO="gdm_end"

LABEL="gdm_disable_wayland"
#RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm-runtime-config set daemon WaylandEnable false"
GOTO="gdm_end"
```

Add # to the two lines like what is shown above (scroll all the way down, both are at the bottom. Save and reboot;
[original solution can be found here by Pablo Bianchi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403854/cant-use-wayland-with-nvidia-510-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts#comment2438039_1403854)

tested and works on 22.04 too. If encounter any problems simply un # the two lines.

Comment: Wayland was not used. X11 is still used.  I think it is because of https://www.phoronix.com/news/Ubuntu-22.04-NVIDIA-XOrg-Back