# Can't use Wayland with Nvidia 510 drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I installed the NVIDIA 510 drivers from the Additional Drivers app on Ubuntu 22.04. I also edited `/etc/default/grub` and added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"`. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I can't see the little gear icon when I login.

Funnily enough I had 21.10 running before this install and it was working in Wayland after editing `/etc/default/grub`.

Here is my setup. It's a very recent Dell Laptop with Secure Boot enabled:

[image: laptop specifications]

Comment: You're probably facing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1969254). I guess you need to compromise with X11 until it gets fixed. I also suggest that you subscribe to the bug and to notifications about it so you get immediately informed when the fix is ready.

Comment: Sane problem here Ci5 10 + nVidia GTX 1650 + driver 510.

In the login screen I can't see the gear, add line to the grub same issue. looks like it's a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1969243

Comment: i thought 22.04 shipped wayland as default and didn't check whether it is running wayland till i saw this post. And i too am having the same issue of not having wayland as a login option. the latest log said it's fixed, however, don't seems to be reflected in the updates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the file `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`
in my case, I just commented the last two one here

```sh
LABEL="gdm_prefer_xorg"
#RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm-runtime-config set daemon PreferredDisplayServer xorg"
GOTO="gdm_end"

LABEL="gdm_disable_wayland"
#RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm-runtime-config set daemon WaylandEnable false"
GOTO="gdm_end"
```

It did work on Ubuntu 22.04 or if still does not work, you can comment something that is related to it.

Comment: The udev file has logic to enable wayland on 510 according to the comments just a few lines above. If its being disabled there is probably a reason. Is commenting out these lines the only way to make 510 work with wayland? This feels like we're using a hammer to turn off the stereo.

Comment: This answer and the answer below (https://askubuntu.com/a/1403999/4928) fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have a desktop computer with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 720 with NVIDIA's proprietary 470 driver. This and Rovano's solutions didn't work for me. Still, my only options after clicking the gear icon are "Ubuntu" or "Gnome Classic".

Answer (score 7):

Two possible solutions:

1. Enable unreleased updates
   [ Alberto Milone ]

   - Default to Wayland for hybrid systems with Nvidia graphics drivers.
   - Default to Xorg but offer Wayland with the gear button on the login screen for non-hybrid systems with Nvidia graphics drivers. (LP: #1968929)
2. Workaround
   Create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf` containing the text:

   ```
   options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1
   ```

Otherwise, follow these bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1969243
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1968929
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1876632

Comment: fixed by updates

Comment: I am using Thinkpad p14s gen 4 AMD with eGPU of Nvidia 2080Ti. I manually installed the Nvidia driver version 535.146.02. This method does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Because `/tmp` is a tmpfs on my system, i need to set

```
options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=/var/tmp
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf`. After rebuilding initramfs with `update-initramfs -u` and a reboot, Wayland is working for me.

Comment: I could confirm this method makes the Wayland option re-appear after a fresh 22.04 install. I chose this approach because I use system hibernation often in my desktop machine and "preserve memory allocations" is required in order to avoid video glitches after resume. I'll report here if I find problems over time.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop):

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
> ```
>
> Within this file, look for the line that says `#WaylandEnable=false`.
> You can uncomment this line and either set it to true or false,
> depending on whether you want Wayland enabled or not.
>
> ```
> WaylandEnable=true
> ```