# Kubuntu 22.04 Wayland with nvidia crashes on launch

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kde, wayland, 22.04

I installed Kubuntu 22.04, and when I switch to Wayland desktop, KDE simply crashes. Here's the report/stacktrace:

```
Application: ksplashqml (ksplashqml), signal: Aborted

[KCrash Handler]
#4  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140469579653440) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#5  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=140469579653440) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#6  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=140469579653440, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#7  0x00007fc1a4629476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#8  0x00007fc1a460f7f3 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#9  0x00007fc1a4acbba3 in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007fc1a3f323e4 in QtWaylandClient::QWaylandDisplay::checkError() const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WaylandClient.so.5
#11 0x00007fc1a3f3311a in QtWaylandClient::QWaylandDisplay::flushRequests() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WaylandClient.so.5
#12 0x00007fc1a4d2c7b8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007fc1a4d2fca3 in QSocketNotifier::activated(QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type, QSocketNotifier::QPrivateSignal) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007fc1a4d304d3 in QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007fc1a4cf4e2a in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#16 0x00007fc1a4d4ecb5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007fc1a2976d1b in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007fc1a29cb6f8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007fc1a29743c3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007fc1a4d4e0a8 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007fc1a4cf374b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007fc1a4cfbce4 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x000055cb5c9e3dba in ?? ()
#24 0x00007fc1a4610d90 in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x55cb5c9e3d40, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fff41026fa8) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#25 0x00007fc1a4610e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x55cb5c9e3d40, argc=1, argv=0x7fff41026fa8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff41026f98) at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#26 0x000055cb5c9e3e25 in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 3842) detached]
```

My nvidia card is: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile

I have nvidia driver 510 installed (the one installed by default)

The command:

```
cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset
```

returns `Y`. [(It seems to be a requirement)](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Wayland/Nvidia)

What else can I do to get it to work?

Why? I need it in hopes to get rid of Windows and start using my touchscreen reasonably well. Currently with X11, it seems like all taps on the screen just move the mouse cursor. Funny enough, even though KDE doesn't start with Wayland, a program that launches on startup launched, and I was able to tap on it properly.

Comment: I think this should be reported to Ubuntu tracker at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ -- ideally with something like `ubuntu-bug qtwayland5` ([doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Collecting_information_from_a_specific_package))

Comment: possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403854/

Comment: Same issue - Kubuntu 22.04, dual GPU (amd + Nvidia). Xorg works, X11 crashes on startup. I've updated to Nvidia 525 drivers and HWE kernel, but with no improvement

Comment: Our stack traces match https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=470090