# In 23.04, when switching virtual desktops, the window that receives focus seems to be the root window, not the last application from that desktop

Tags: gnome, window, 23.04, virtualdesktop

In previous versions, when switching virtual desktops focus was attached to the last window focused on such desktop.

In 23.04 (running Gnome), when I switch virtual desktops the focus seems to always go to root window. Is this a bug or a configurable behavior?

This is really inconvenient, because it adds so much friction to virtual desktops workflow to make it virtually pointless.

EDIT:
This is a duplicate of [Active window loosing focus when switching workspace - Ubuntu 22.04 / GNOME 42](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407281/active-window-loosing-focus-when-switching-workspace-ubuntu-22-04-gnome-42)
and same solution applies.

Comment: I believe the question duplicated this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407281/active-window-loosing-focus-when-switching-workspace-ubuntu-22-04-gnome-42. It's a bug in gnome Icons NG extension.

Comment: Indeed, it was. Thanks for the pointer. :-)