# Why is Wayland not an option in Ubuntu 22.04 with NVIDIA graphics?

Tags: wayland, 22.04

Wayland should come as default windows system for Ubuntu 22.04 but still I see X11 , how I switch to wayland.

[system specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8epO.png)

Comment: Canonical reverted DM back to X.org for those computers with NVDIA graphics cards in the last minute of the release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. See [this post](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-22.04-NVIDIA-XOrg-Back).

Answer (score 0):

Just logout and before login again, you'll see an small icon at the bottom of the right corner. Just click there choose Wayland. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKNVc.png)

Comment: the icon is not showing

Comment: @Wael_Al_Rebh if the icon is not available at the login screen. You can try the solution listed in the answer [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403570/can-not-switch-to-waylan-in-22-04/1404785#1404785)

Comment: Thank you very much @Fpinheiro , this work